# Got a fatal error with qtranslate-xp

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, qtranslate

I reinstalled a website after upgrading to wordpress 4.8.1 and I have a fatal error when I activate the qtranslate-xp plugin:

> Cannot redeclare qs_base64_serialize() (previously declared in /home/xxx/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_services.php:80) in /home/xxx/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-xp/ppqtranslate_services.php on line 91

Here are the lines:

```
// serializing/deserializing functions
function qs_base64_serialize($var) {
    if(is_array($var)) {
        foreach($var as $key => $value) {
            $var[$key] = qs_base64_serialize($value);
        }
    }
    $var = serialize($var);
    $var = strtr(base64_encode($var), '-_,', '+/=');
    return $var;
}
```

I tried to comment these lines but I got an other fatal error later on.

It seems that qtranslate main plugin (`Version 2.5.39 | By Qian Qin`) is correctly activated but doesn't work.
Qtranslate Plus: `Version 2.7.2 | By Papa Salvatore Mirko (Originally created by Qian Qin`).

Actually, these 2 plugin pages are not accessible anymore and I couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [qtranslate-xp](https://github.com/gregq/qtranslate-xp) GitHub page:

> **IMPORTANT**: This is not an Extension of the official qTranslate.
>
> qTranslate Plus is an unOfficial modified version of qTranslate.

Since the qTranslate-xp is a whole plugin and not an add-on to qTranslate, you should remove or at least deactivate the original qTranslate plugin.

As it is now, you have both original and forked version of the plugin activated on your website, so this might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well... I did it first and had the same fatal error... And was confused. But, you're right! I did it again and it seems to work now. Big and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
if (!function_exists('qs_base64_serialize')) {
function qs_base64_serialize(){
 if(is_array($var)) {
    foreach($var as $key => $value) {
        $var[$key] = qs_base64_serialize($value);
    }
 }
 $var = serialize($var);
 $var = strtr(base64_encode($var), '-_,', '+/=');
 return $var;
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake now please check

Comment: Thx for your response. I did it and also to the qs_base64_unserialize which is the same pattern. And the fatal error will be later though with the next function called: // sends a encrypted message to qTranslate Services and decrypts the received data.
I was wondering if the problem wouldn't come from the www.qianqin.de website which is unaccessible so far.

Comment: Unfortunately. Nope.